# D3.js Force links to node border

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nodes

I have been trying to experiment with D3.js and while this question may sound silly, I am not capable of making the links in a graph point to the node borders instead of the node centers.

I have been using the following jsfiddle to test it, but I am still not able to do it...

http://jsfiddle.net/blonkm/zpcJa/40/light/

I suppose that I have to update something in the tick() function to return different values:

```
function tick() {
  path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = 0; // straight lines (0=straight, 1=round)
        // alternatively use dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); for similar arcs
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
  });

  circle.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });

  text.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
  });
}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to making it appear as if the links are pointing to the border is to draw the links first and then the nodes on top of them. This way, the circles will obscure the line segments that go to the center.

All you have to do for this is reorder the code, i.e. append the `path` elements before the `circle`s.

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zpcJa/66/).

Comment: Wow I cant believe it was that simple... Thanks!

Comment: But what about the use-case where I need the transparent circles with zero 'fill-opacity'? Is there any way, how to do it?

Comment: @TomasJavurek See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16660193/get-arrowheads-to-point-at-outer-edge-of-node-in-d3