# How to calculate a modified Path for different size circle in Force directed arrow graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geometry, force-layout

My question is further modification of Force directed graph from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/ericcoopey/707dc711806a34f5c56e). Here from every source to target it has a arrow at the target end this works fine however if we stick to the theory that all circle are with radius 5.

However in my case I have modified the example that all the nodes will be of different radius based on a parameter, so in such scenario the arrow hides behind the target as the radius is big so the path and arrow hides beside, Im not looking for a solution to bring path and arrow in front instead what I'm trying is to find the new point. In layman language I need to subtract the radius unit from the path so that I get a point on the outer circle.

Sample fiddle is [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/3uehrfj8/)

I guess some modification to this code will be required here in tick function

```
  function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" +
                d.source.x + "," +
                d.source.y + "A" +
                dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
                d.target.x + "," +
                d.target.y;
   });
```

I tried to modify this code as [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vm9jswLm/2/) but not a good fix it behaving weird Can anyone please comment how can we calculate this point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "classic" solution (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16754080/5768908)):

```
path.attr("d", function(d) {

    diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
    diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

    pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

    offsetX = (diffX * d.target.radius) / pathLength;
    offsetY = (diffY * d.target.radius) / pathLength;


    var dx = (d.target.x - offsetX) - d.source.x,
        dy = (d.target.y - offsetY) - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" +
        d.source.x + "," +
        d.source.y + "A" +
        dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
        (d.target.x - offsetX) + "," +
        (d.target.y - offsetY);
});
```

The only problem with this math is that the arc starts and ends in the *straight line*  going from the source to the target. That gives the impression that the arrowhead is a little bit "to the right".

Here is the demo:

```js
// get the data
var graph = {
    "nodes": [{
        "name": "Ilya I",
        "group": 0
    }, {
        "name": "Betty  B",
        "group": 1
    }, {
        "name": "Andy N",
        "group": 2
    }, {
        "name": "Harper P",
        "group": 3
    }, {
        "name": "Holly V",
        "group": 4
    }, {
        "name": "Elijah W",
        "group": 5
    }, {
        "name": "Kalvin L",
        "group": 6
    }, {
        "name": "Chris  D",
        "group": 7
    }, {
        "name": "Alexa U",
        "group": 8
    }],
    "links": [{
        "source": 2,
        "target": 5,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 6,
        "value": 3,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 7,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 2,
        "target": 8,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 4,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 6,
        "value": 2,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 7,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 3,
        "target": 8,
        "value": 3,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 5,
        "target": 5,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }, {
        "source": 6,
        "target": 2,
        "value": 1,
        "type": "arrow"
    }]
};

var nodecolor = d3.scale.category20();

var nodes = {};

// Compute the distinct nodes from the links.
var links = graph.links;

var width = 500,
    height = 400;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(links)
    .size([width, height])
    .linkDistance(function(d) {
        return 1 / d.value * 250;
    })
    .charge(-500)
    .on("tick", tick)
    .start();

// Set the range
var v = d3.scale.linear().range([0, 100]);

// Scale the range of the data
v.domain([0, d3.max(links, function(d) {
    return d.value;
})]);

// asign a type per value to encode opacity
links.forEach(function(link) {
    if (v(link.value) <= 25) {
        link.type = "twofive";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 50 && v(link.value) > 25) {
        link.type = "fivezero";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 75 && v(link.value) > 50) {
        link.type = "sevenfive";
    } else if (v(link.value) <= 100 && v(link.value) > 75) {
        link.type = "onezerozero";
    }
});

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// build the arrow.
svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"]) // Different link/path types can be defined here
    .enter().append("svg:marker") // This section adds in the arrows
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 10)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("svg:path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

// add the links and the arrows
var path = svg.append("svg:g").selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links())
    .enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link " + d.type;
    })
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");

// define the nodes
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(force.nodes())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    //.on("click", click)
    //.on("dblclick", dblclick)
    .call(force.drag);

// add the nodes
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        d.radius = d.group * 5;
        return d.radius
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return nodecolor(d.group);
    });

// add the text
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.name;
    });

// add the curvy lines
function tick() {
    path.attr("d", function(d) {

        diffX = d.target.x - d.source.x;
        diffY = d.target.y - d.source.y;

        pathLength = Math.sqrt((diffX * diffX) + (diffY * diffY));

        offsetX = (diffX * d.target.radius) / pathLength;
        offsetY = (diffY * d.target.radius) / pathLength;


        var dx = (d.target.x - offsetX) - d.source.x,
            dy = (d.target.y - offsetY) - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" +
            d.source.x + "," +
            d.source.y + "A" +
            dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " +
            (d.target.x - offsetX) + "," +
            (d.target.y - offsetY);
    });

    node.attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        });
}

// action to take on mouse click
function click() {
    d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", 22)
        .style("fill", "steelblue")
        .style("stroke", "lightsteelblue")
        .style("stroke-width", ".5px");
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 16)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return nodecolor(d.group);
        });
}

// action to take on mouse double click
function dblclick() {
    d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r", 6)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return nodecolor(d.group);
        });
    d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("x", 12)
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("fill", "black")
        .style("stroke", "none")
        .style("font", "10px sans-serif");
}
```

```css
path.link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: #666;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    path.link.twofive {
        opacity: 0.25;
    }

    path.link.fivezero {
        opacity: 0.50;
    }

    path.link.sevenfive {
        opacity: 0.75;
    }

    path.link.onezerozero {
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    circle {
        fill: #ccc;
        stroke: #fff;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    text {
        fill: #000;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
    #content {
        padding: 7px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to show the marker in the middle

doing like this:

```
.attr("marker-mid", "url(#end)");
```

instead of

```
.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");
```

working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/e29qncm2/)

Comment: Yeah this is also an good alternative at least the context remains same, Is there anything you find with the point to be calculated that would really help me